# How old is Omega?

Tags: star-wars, the-bad-batch

In the second to last episode of Bad Batch Season 1, it is revealed that:

> Omega was created before the clone force 99

But Omega looks to be around 10-11 years old.

[image]

And we know that the clones had to be trained for nine years before being deployed. And Omega remembers the other bad batch clones being created which means she couldn't have been a baby or something. And how long the bad batch has been deployed makes a difference as well.

So how old is Omega really? Is she as old as her appearance would suggest, or is she older?

Comment: we know she's older than Wreeeeeka

Comment: If she's an unaltered clone like Boba, then she ages naturally and should be around his age, which is 13.  That's my guess.

Answer (score 8):

### We dont know EXACTLY how old Omega is, yet.

From [How old is Omega in The Bad Batch? She’s not the youngest clone](https://dorksideoftheforce.com/2021/08/13/how-old-is-omega-the-bad-batch/)

> At the end of season 1, we also learned the truth about Omega’s age. Though the Bad Batch appear to be adults and Omega presents as a child, their ages aren’t so conventional.
>
> ### *The Bad Batch: How old is Omega?*
>
> While **we don’t know Omega’s exact age in numbers yet**, it was implied in episode 15 — and confirmed in episode 16 — that **she is older than the other members of the Bad Batch**. She was already old enough to remember them being experimented on in Nala Se’s private lab before leaving her alone again.
>
> Like Boba Fett, **Omega does not appear to age at an accelerated rate** as other Kamino-born clones do. So even though Hunter and the rest of her brothers are technically older because they age faster, at the time of The Bad Batch, **she has been alive longer in standard years**.
>
> **Unfortunately, since we don’t know *when* she was created, there’s no telling exactly how old she is**. Though, from her appearance and normal aging, she should be about the age of a typical adolescent child, just still comparatively older than the Bad Batch.
>
> ...
>
> We will likely learn more about Omega’s origins and former life on Kamino in season 2 as she comes to terms with losing the only place she ever called home.